What is the meaning of confidence intervals when NOT using sample data and instead have data on the whole population?
I'm trying to understand why you would need confidence intervals or compute statistical tests (for comparing proportions) when your data is NOT from a sample and you have data on the whole population.
My example.
In 2014, 100 people died at an intensive care unit. 40 of the deceased had indicated before they died that they wanted to donate their organs upon death. So, the percentage of deceased with a positive attitude was 40%. The remaining 60% were either negative or had not indicated their will before death. In 2015, 120 people died at an intensive care unit. 60 of them had indicated before they died that they wanted to donate their organs upon death. So, the percentage of deceased with a positive attitude in 2015 was 50%. The remaining 50% were either negative or had not indicated their will before death.
Now to my question.
We know that the proportion has increased from 40% to 50% between 2014 and 2015. Do we really need to construct confidence intervals around both proportions to be sure that the increase is significant? Or do we really need to carry out a statistical test (suggested test?) to be sure that the percentage has actually increased?
I’ve heard that you might want to construct confidence intervals and that the confidence interval then controls for ”natural variability”, when working with population data.
Also, if someone has some literature on this topic I would greatly appreciate some links.

Unless you are content with historical description of completed facts. you do not have a "population."  You have two years of data from an ongoing process.

Yes, you need to run a test, specifically a 2x2 contingency matrix, which in your case would show that this change is not significant (p=.09, for a single sided Fisher exact test, $H_a$: proportion 2015>proportion 2014). Because there is randomness each year (random # of deaths, random # of donations)
